# How to create multi-level side menu in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface

I want to create menu similar to this image but I am not sure how to start in Angular

[Image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INq6b.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, I would recommend you first to take a while to look at [Stackoverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), this would give you an idea how to start writing a good post. 
About your question: are your menu levels finite or infinite ? (I mean you have an idea what can be the limit or you can have a lot without a restrections) ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely take a look at it. Coming back to your question the number of menus is fixed maximum it will go is up to 4 levels.